# Best javascript combo box?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, combobox, autocomplete

A combo box is an auto-complete text box that is also a dropdown (i.e., you can choose from a list if you prefer).

"Best" means combination of: stable, look/feel, API / customizability, maturity.

Comment: [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) is the most complete, stable and feature rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the [Yahoo UI Autocomplete widget](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/autocomplete/).  It does not provide the dropdown natively, but a dropdown button can be added with [a few lines of code](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/ydn-javascript/message/30178).

Answer (score 3):

[ExtJS](http://extjs.com/) has a [very powerful combo box](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.ComboBox) that provides [dropdown, auto-complete, and filtering of choices](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/combos.html).  You can also enable [pagination](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/forum-search.html),

There are a number of extensions that provide additional capabilities, such as a [Facebook style multi-select](http://extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=33794&highlight=combo+extension), or [multi-select checkboxes](http://lovcombo.extjs.eu/).

Answer (score 0):

This is of course a subjective question, but I have good experiences on with [Script.aculo.us](http://script.aculo.us/)'s autocompleter ([API docs here](http://github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/wikis/ajax-autocompleter)). It's been around for quite a while, browser support is excellent, you can customize look and feel, etc.

Note that Script.aculo.us depends on [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/).

Answer (score -1):

Surely autocomplete and combo boxes serve two similar, but different purposes:

- Autocomplete; select one from a very long list (i.e. too long to scroll through)
- ComboBox; select one from a relatively short list (i.e. one that is easy to scroll through

How many items do you have in your list?